# Access restfulAPI token using R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

My project includes fetching the token from restful API using **R**. The API uses OAuth 2.0. The project is confidential, so cannot provide the information.

Can anyone please help me to access the token using coding in **R**? For instance:

URL: facebook.com
username: ABC
Password: qwerty

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that can be considered for Facebook :

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://www.facebook.com/"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("css selector", '#email')
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("ABC"))

web_Obj_Password <- remDr$findElement("css selector", '#pass')
web_Obj_Password$sendKeysToElement(list("qwerty"))

html_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

id_Submit <- unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(html_Content, 'royal_login_button" type="submit" id=".........'))
id_Submit <- stringr::str_extract_all(id_Submit, 'id=".........')
id_Submit <- stringr::str_remove_all(id_Submit, 'id|=|\"')

web_Obj_Submit <- remDr$findElement("id", id_Submit)
web_Obj_Submit$click()
```